# Listening to a different process's socket?

Tags: bash, sockets, exec

I have one process (PID1) that does:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/12713
```

And when I do:

```
$ ls -lh /proc/self/fd/
lrwx------ 1 0 0 64 Mar 24 12:19 0 -> /dev/pts/9
lrwx------ 1 0 0 64 Mar 24 12:19 1 -> /dev/pts/9
lrwx------ 1 0 0 64 Mar 24 12:19 2 -> /dev/pts/9
lrwx------ 1 0 0 64 Mar 24 12:20 255 -> /dev/pts/9
lrwx------ 1 0 0 64 Mar 24 12:19 3 -> socket:[83968639]
```

Now let's say I have a second process PID2, is it possible to read the socket opened through the PID1?

I have tried:

```
exec 1>/proc/PID1/fd/3
```

but i get the error message: `No such device or address`

My scenario has the PID1 writing to the socket and PID2 reading it. (basically for experimentation with the file descriptors)

Comment: That would only be possible if PID2 is a child process of PID1 (Or you open the socket in the parent process that both PID1 and PID2 are childs of)

Comment: There are more efficient ways for two processes on the same machine to communicate than via the network stack.

Comment: It's not an inter-process communication, the PID1 is supposed to send commands to the server and the PID2 is supposed to read the response from the server